# What has a higher probability of occurring?

Tags: probability

What has a higher probability of occurring:
a 5 card flush (5 cards with the same suit) or a 7 card straight (where a straight is cannot "chain" from ... King Ace 2 ...) 
Ex: Valid: ACE 1 2 3 4 5 6 AND ACE K Q J 10 9 8 7
Invalid: Q K ACE 1 2 3 4

I got in an argument with my friend after playing a card game and I want to know what is more difficult to get.

Comment: Consider explaining what is a flush and a straight. Not everybody here plays poker. (I guess it is poker).

Comment: 5 card flush: 5 cards with the same suit. ie 5 hearts, or 5 diamonds (but the face values do not matter, ie 1 2 3 4....)

Comment: For the flush, we take 5 random cards out of 52, is it?

Comment: And what is the total of the cards?

Comment: 52 card deck, each suit has 13 values (Ace 2 ... J Q K), 4 possible suits (Heart, Spade, Diamond, "Clover")

Comment: This question isn't clear.  Do you receive 5 cards for the flush, and 7 cards for the straight, or 7 in each case?

Comment: The chain that is not allowed is between King and Ace, or Ace and 2? (well, it won't change the result, but just to know).

Comment: @Paul You keep drawing until you get one or the other.

Comment: @toliveira The chain is NOT allowed for King to Ace to Two. Chain IS allowed for both Ace and King, as well as Ace and Two. Sorry if that made it confusing, I guess it won't really affect the probability any ways..

Comment: The types of "chains" that are allowed _do_ affect the probability, because they determine how many ways you can have a seven-card straight at any point in the game when at least seven cards have been dealt, which determines the probability that one of those ways occurred.

Comment: @bobdylan, that's a very different question than the one you stated.

Comment: So would the probability of a 7 card straight be: 4/(52*51*50*49*48*47*46) and the probability of a 5 card flush be: (13*12*11*10*9*8)/(52*51*50*49*48)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see.

The number of ways of getting a $5$-card flush is $4 \binom {13} 5$, as we have $4$ suits to choose from and $13$ cards in each suit. The total number of ways to choose five cards from a deck of $52$ is $\binom {52} 5$. So the probability is $\dfrac {33} {16660}$. Small indeed.

The number of ways to get a $7$-card straight is $8 \cdot 4^7$, as we can have any string from A-2-3-4-5-6-7 to 8-9-10-J-Q-K-A, and the cards can come from any suit. The total number of ways to choose seven cards from a deck of $52$ is $\binom {52} 7$. So the probability is $\dfrac {8192} {8361535}$. This is extremely small.

It is more likely to get a $5$-card flush.

Comment: Would the answer for the straight be the same if 2 3 4 5 6 7 8, 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, etc are allowed too?

Comment: The straight calculation that I provided includes all straights. For example, 3-4-5-6-7-8-9 is included. This is why I multiplied 4^7 by 8 - to include all the straights.

Comment: This doesn't account for the possibility that you get a five-card flush in the first six or seven cards, nor (more importantly!) what happens afterward if you don't see either event in the first seven cards.

Comment: The problem was asking whether a 5-card flush or a 7-card straight was more probable. Since the problem did NOT specify that cards were being drawn until one of the two instances occurred, this solution is correct. It is irrelevant that a player may not get either in the first 7 cards, because that's not what the question was asking. The question just wanted to compare P(flush) and P(straight). @David K

Comment: The question itself is unclear about what it means. Someone commented to ask for clarification, and OP replied in a comment, "You keep drawing until you get one or the other." So the answer above is a good answer based on a reasonable interpretation of the question as posted, but not quite an answer to the question OP evidently _wanted_ to ask. (It's still a very good start toward an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Probability of the 5 card flush P = E1*E2*E3*E4*E5, where Ei is the probability of a event as follows:

E1 - take one card (E1=1=52/52)
E2 - take one card of the same suit as the previous one (E2 = 12/51)
E3 - 11/50
E4 - 10/49
E5 - 9/48

P = 0.001981

Answer (score 0):

The real question is more complicated than it looks, because
(as stated in a comment) you keep drawing cards until one of the
two patterns occurs.

According to that statement, it would appear that the following sequence
of cards drawn from the deck would count as "five-card flush occurs first":

$$ 5S, 7S, 2H, KC, 10S, JD, AS, 2S, \ldots $$

In this case we had to draw eight cards before we drew the fifth spade,
at which point we still had no seven-card straight.
The symbol "$\ldots$" is meant to indicate that we could have kept on
drawing more cards if we had not already gotten one of the desired outcomes.

You can compute the probability that the flush will occur before
the straight and that the straight will occur before the flush,
but the best idea I have for doing this involves a long, tedious procedure.
Some of the steps of this procedure are as follows.
(I have abbreviated "five-card flush" as $F_5$ and
"seven-card straight" as $S_7$ in order to make this a little less wordy.)

1. Compute the probability of an $F_5$ in the first $6$ cards.
2. Compute the probability that there is an $F_5$ in the first $7$ cards but no $F_5$ in the first $6$ cards.
3. Compute the probability that there is an $S_7$ in the first $7$ cards
   but no $F_5$ in the first $6$ cards.
4. Compute the probability that there is both an $F_5$ and an $S_7$ in the first $7$ cards but no $F_5$ in the first $6$ cards.
5. Compute the probability that there is an $F_5$ in the first $8$ cards but neither an $F_5$ nor an $S_7$ in the first $7$ cards.
6. Compute the probability that there is an $S_7$ in the first $8$ cards but neither an $F_5$ nor an $S_7$ in the first $7$ cards.
7. Compute the probability that there is both an $F_5$ and an $S_7$ in the first $8$ cards but neither an $F_5$ nor an $S_7$ in the first $7$ cards.

And so forth. There are three subsequences within the list:
events where you have an $F_5$, events where you have an $S_7$,
and events where you have both. 
Add up the probabilities in each sequence of events separately.
You can stop after $17$ cards, because it is guaranteed
that you will have gotten a five-card flush by then.

You might be able to stop even earlier if one of the partial sums
of probabilities gets larger than either of the other two possibly could be.
My guess is the five-card-flush is more likely and will be found to be so
before you have to examine $17$ cards, based on the early "lead" that
it establishes.